# set variable to a variable that already exists based on name of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets assume, when the page is rendered i have a variable that looks like:

`var test1 = 'this is a string of html'`

I have a function that looks like :

```
  function addRow(v) {
    $.each(v, function (k,v) {
      if (k == 'jsvar') {
        cableHTML = 'test1'
        insertCabling(parentId, cableHTML)
      }
    });
  }
```

the variable that `cableHTML` is set to is dependent on `jsvar`'s value.  So it will change depending on whats selected.

`test1` might be `test2`, or something else. test1/test2/test3 etc, all exist as variables on the page when its loads. the value pair of `jsvar` dictates what variable `cableHTML` needs to be.

I want to set `cableHTML` to the `test` variables that were loaded earler.  Is there (hopefully) a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: as long as it's in scope... just remove the quotes around test1. also, do you realize you are making `cableHTML` a global variable?

Comment: sorry, i didn't include important info -- test1 might be test2, or something else.  Test1/test2/test3 etc, all exist as variables on the page when its loads.  the value pair of 'jsvar' dictates what variable cableHTML needs to be

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an array instead of multiple indexed variable names. Then do something like `cableHTML = testArray[v];`

Comment: Important question - from where you know which variable you want to assign? test1, test2 or test3?

Comment: i think smerny is on point here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you said "the value pair of jsvar dictates what variable `cableHTML` needs to be", assuming that value is `test1`, `test2`, etc. You could do this:

```
  function addRow(v) {
    $.each(v, function (k,v) {
      if (k == 'jsvar') {
        cableHTML = eval("v");
        insertCabling(parentId, cableHTML)
      }
    });
  }
```

But you would be better off using an array (`eval()` and indexed variable names are something you should always try to avoid), and doing something like:

```
  function addRow(v) {
    $.each(v, function (k,v) {
      if (k == 'jsvar') {
        cableHTML = myArray[v];
        insertCabling(parentId, cableHTML)
      }
    });
  }
```

Where the value for `jsvar` is the key for the item you want in your `myArray` array.

Also, if you aren't declaring `var cableHTML` somewhere else in this scope, you are making it a global var. As you are passing it as a parameter to `insertCabling()` I assume you don't want/need a global and you should just add `var` to `cableHTML = ...`

---

Also after looking at your code more, it seems the `each()` is unnecessary:

```
  function addRow(row) {
    if(row["jsvar"]){
      insertCabling(parentId, row["jsvar"]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks . this is exactly what i needed.  I tried doing an array .. but the code im working on is just so old and ugly, its hard to do anything better.

Comment: @RickyMason, I'm not sure if you've seen I've added to my answer (about removing the `each()` loop). If you are using `eval()` (which you shouldn't), you could do something like this in place of the entire `each()` block: `try { (row["jsvar"] && insertCabling(parentId, eval(row["jsvar"])));} catch (e) {}`. also note i changed the `addRow()` parameter name to `row`.

Comment: Thank you. I worked in your suggested changes and its working great now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the quotes around `test1` and `jsvar` in your code, unless you want k to be equal to the string `'jsvar'` and you want cableHTML to be equal to `'test'`.

```
var test1 = 'this is a string of html';

function addRow(v) {
  $.each(v, function(k,v) {
    if (k == jsvar) {
      cableHTML = test1
      insertCabling(parentId, cableHTML)
    }
  });
}
```